# SQLITE query monthly GROUP BY with SUM

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I have been stuck with this problem for a while (Android SQLITE). I have 2 columns - Date and Amount. Date is stored in YYYYMMDD format.

### DATE           AMOUNT

20120521-------50
20120506-------40
20120311-------30
20120202-------20
20120125-------10

What I need is a SQL query (Android SQLITE), which will output two columns - Month and cumulative total till that month..If a month does not have any transaction, it still should evaluate the cummulative total.

So the output I need here (notice there are no transactions for April)

### Month        Cumulative-Total

MAY-------150
APR-------60
MAR-------60
FEB-------30
JAN-------10

Comment: i dont think you can use the `sql query sentence` to get the result that you want, if use `group`, it group what ? the `date` ? no, your date also different, you want to sum all amounts in one month, may be you need do filter in the code except the query.

Answer (score 2):

It should work:

```
SELECT  strftime('%m', date), SUM(Amount)
FROM    myTable
GROUP BY strftime('%m', date)
```

Sorry i forgot this part of your question "..If a month does not have any transaction, it still should evaluate the cummulative total."

Solution: The simple solution is to have a DUMMY entry in the table for all months.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult since the easy way to do this is to write a stored procedure to do it but which isnt supported in sqlite. However take a look at this - maybe this way might be useful
[Android - easy/efficient way to maintain a "cumulative sum" for a SQLite column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723299/android-easy-efficient-way-to-maintain-a-cumulative-sum-for-a-sqlite-column)
Also you can try doing the cumulative addition on the android end

Answer (score -1):

you can not just comulate like this. You can do this 2 ways:

1. Group by month and then sum it up on the Android end and add the Months that missing.
2. Try make that with a store procedure. (this I am not entierly sure possable on sql lite for your case.) Read [this](http://chriswolf.heroku.com/articles/2011/01/26/adding-stored-procedures-to-sqlite)

So I would go with the first option.

Comment: Stored procedures are not available in sqlite.